# How to change screen background in assembler

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

This is for homework:

How do I clear the screen and change foreground and background colors in assembler (NASM on windows)

EDIT: It turns out the answer is something like

```
mov bh, 71h
int 10h
```

Comment: You tag this as windows. Are you creating a window by calling `CreateWindow`? If not, then how are you planning on interacting with the display?

Comment: @David, I added the [windows], [x86], and [nasm] tags based on the mention of 'NASM on windows' in the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [FillConsoleOutputCharacter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need some operating system services to get that kind of functionality.  Since that's a requirement, how would you do it from another language?  Once you figure that out, you can just make the same calls from your assembly language program.  Something like:

```
call OSServiceClearScreen
```

where `OSServiceClearScreen` is the name of the system call or library function that performs the operation you want.  Then just link your assembly program with the right libraries and it should all "just work".